# <a href> deleting an item without sending user to another page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have a single page rails app that creates an item along with the delete link which looks like this in a file called _new_list.html (a script of type text/template to be added using AJAX):

```
<a href="/to_do_lists/<%= list.id %>" data-method="delete">Delete</a>
```

The problem is this link sends the user to /to_do_lists/(list id) instead of staying in the same page. The delete link in erb that works for existing items loaded with erb looks like this:

```
  <%= link_to "Delete",
      to_do_list_url(list),
      :method => :delete,
      :remote => true %>
```

Unfortunately I think I have to use  because I cannot put any rails code in the template. What is the way to delete the item without sending the user to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your destroy method within your controller, and remove the redirect_to path

```
def destroy
      @to_do_list = Todolist.find( params[:id] )

      @to_do_list.destroy

      #redirect_to this_path
      #Remove the redirect_to
end
```

Then you can let ajax remove the element from the page

Comment: If I don't put anything after destroying the list in the controller, the server responds by saying there is a missing template. What I did was to render :json. It works for the link_to "Delete" in the erb, but it doesn't work for the raw HTML <a>.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the generated link and your manual anchor tag is that you're missing the data-remote="true" attribute on your anchor tag.

Also, instead of render :json, you might want to render the same partial by specifying its name like render "partialname". redirect_to causes a redirect, while render allows you to stay on the same page and render the updated list partial with the item now removed.

Comment: But once the template is added to the index.html.erb page, should it belong to the actual page instead of the partial? I am confused on how the destroy action (by rendering json or partial) affects the removal of the item through AJAX because the script to delete items works for the rails generated delete link but not the manual anchor tag (even after adding data-remote="true"). Thanks!